# Create a conditional relay based on email subject using Exchange?

Tags: email, exchange, microsoft-office-365

Note: I am not the server admin and am not greatly familiar with exchange.  I am a developer working with our exchange team.

We have a mailbox which receives incoming customer emails for our support system.  Due to a new system setup (Salesforce Service Cloud), we have two different conditions where we wish to relay the email coming into this mailbox to a different mailbox, based on the content of the subject.  The email should relay *AS IS* with no header changes to the 'from' address.  Right now we're using client rules in outlook to forward but this creates a *new* email from the mailbox in question which screws up how Salesforce processes it.

Our regular exchange admin is on extended PTO and his backups are not familiar with how - or even if - this can be done.

Basically if subject contains text matching one of two ref types then we want to relay the mail to the right end point mailbox in salesforce.  Otherwise the mail should remain in this mailbox.

Ie:

- Mail msg 1 subject contains '.500' or '._500' forward to salesforce
  inbox 1 Mail
- msg 2 subject contains 'ref:0WO' - forward to salesforce
  inbox 2
- Else- leave in inbox

Can this be done, and how?

Comment: You need to contact your exchange admin to create a transport rule to redirect the message to the right end point mailbox in salesforce.

Comment: I'm thinking you didn't really read the whole content, did you?